# How can i populate the modal with the values recivied from Ajax call?

Tags: jquery

On click of the Show Hyper Link, it makes a Ajax call and fetches some values and with the values received from Ajax call i want to show the modal.

sample code

```
$("#anchor_myModal").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_url', 
        type: 'form_method',      
        data: 'form_data',     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){    
            alert('success called');
        }           
    });  
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/61ky7h2m/9/

Could you please let me know how to make this work?

Comment: why negative points , atleast please some tip on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your success function.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Complete code

```
$("#anchor_myModal").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
            url: 'form_url', 
            type: 'form_method',      
            data: 'form_data',     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){    
              $('#myModal').modal('show');

            }           
        });  
});
```

Comment: thanks when i put your code , i am getting the following error $(...).model is not a function  and this is updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/61ky7h2m/11/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change your a tag to the below so the modal does not open on click of the link:

`<a id="anchor_myModal" role="button" data-tt="tooltip" title="hi">Show</a>`

Then change your ajax call to :

```
$("#anchor_myModal").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
            url: 'form_url', 
            type: 'form_method',      
            data: 'form_data',     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){  
              var $modal=$('#myModal');
              $modal.find('.modal-body').html(returnhtml);
              $modal.modal('show');
            }           
        });  
});
```